# Create pivot table with one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

I am not even sure how to title this question. If you can give me a better title I will update the question.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Column Title: Status
               A
             (blank)
               B
               C
               C
             (blank)
               B
```

I want the pivot table to use the row labels as A,B,C,(blank) but I also want the count of each. Can this be done without another column in a pivot table?

For example:

```
   "Status" | count
          A | 1
          B | 2
          C | 2
    (blank) | 2
```

If not how can I aggregate the data?

Ultimately the goal is to pie chart the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, select the Status column (up to the last row) and insert a Pivot Table. Drag the Status field under Row label, and drag the Status field again under Values as well (you'll get Count of Status).

However, it won't count blanks. For that you should see if you can include more columns in your PivotTable so that you have at least one column that is never blank - it doesn't matter what it contains or if the column is left or right of Status. Create a pivot table for those columns, separate row labels by Status again, but this time count by another field which you know is never empty. You'll get the same result but blanks will be counted.

Comment: I didn't realize in the new 2016 layout for pivot tables that you can do that. Simple enough. Thanks!